# Unique Key Error while trying to trim column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to trim leading and trailing spaces in SQL Server using this code:

```
Update MyTable
   SET Column_Name=ltrim(rtrim(Column_Name))
```

But when I do so, I keep getting this error message:

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 24
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UC_MyTable'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'MyTable'.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some kind of simple workaround?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here, your `UPDATE` statement would create duplicate values in your column, and your column must be `UNIQUE`.

Comment: FYI you can use TRIM function in place of LTRIM / RTRIM combination if using a current version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems pretty clear.  You have a unique constraint on the column.  When you remove leading and trailing spaces, then you are getting identical values.  For instance, if you have the following names:

```
'   a'
'a'
```

Then they are different.  But if you remove the spaces from the first one, then they are the same and you get a violation of the unique constraint.

You could identify the offending values using:

```
select *
from (select Column_Name, count(*) over (partition by ltrim(rtrim(Column_Name))) as cnt
      from mytable t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2
order by ltrim(rtrim(Column_Name));
```

Comment: Seems to be it! Thanks for clarifying!